axios error throw ERR_NETWORK on external API call
Using React-native, I try to get a return of a list of the currency. On the browser it work fine, here is the result of the link
https://api.getgeoapi.com/v2/currency/convert?api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:
{
"base_currency_code": "EUR",
"base_currency_name": "Euro",
"amount": "1.0000",
"updated_date": "2024-04-14",
"rates": {
    "PLN": {
         "currency_name": "Polish złoty",
         "rate": "4.2888",
          "rate_for_amount": "4.2888"
}, 
...

Here is my code, and its working perfectly on another API call on my project:
axios.get(currencyURL, {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' }
        })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log("response: ", response.data.rates);
                setResponseCurr(response.data.rates)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log("API ERROR : ", JSON.stringify(error, null, 4));
            })

And here is the result of the error:
{
    "message": "Network Error",
    "name": "AxiosError",
    "stack": "AxiosError: Network Error\n    at handleError (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.policrypto&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:94505:39)\n    at call (native)\n    at dispatchEvent (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.policrypto&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:27753:31)\n    at setReadyState (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.policrypto&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:27027:33)\n    at __didCompleteResponse (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.policrypto&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:26838:29)\n    at apply (native)\n    at anonymous (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.policrypto&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:26963:52)\n    at apply (native)\n    at emit (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.policrypto&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:1744:40)\n    at apply (native)\n    at __callFunction (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.policrypto&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:2425:36)\n    at anonymous (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.policrypto&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:2187:31)\n    at __guard (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.policrypto&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:2377:15)\n    at callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.policrypto&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:2186:21)\n    at ?anon_0_ (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.policrypto&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:93164:64)\n    at throw (native)\n    at asyncGeneratorStep (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.policrypto&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:20759:26)\n    at _throw (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.policrypto&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:20781:29)\n    at tryCallOne (/root/react-native/ReactAndroid/hermes-engine/.cxx/Release/141v2f1g/x86_64/lib/InternalBytecode/InternalBytecode.js:53:16)\n    at anonymous (/root/react-native/ReactAndroid/hermes-engine/.cxx/Release/141v2f1g/x86_64/lib/InternalBytecode/InternalBytecode.js:139:27)\n    at apply (native)\n    at anonymous (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.policrypto&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:26327:26)\n    at _callTimer (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.policrypto&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:26246:17)\n    at _callReactNativeMicrotasksPass (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.policrypto&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:26276:17)\n    at callReactNativeMicrotasks (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.policrypto&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:26439:44)\n    at __callReactNativeMicrotasks (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.policrypto&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:2393:46)\n    at anonymous (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.policrypto&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:2205:45)\n    at __guard (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.policrypto&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:2377:15)\n    at flushedQueue (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.policrypto&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:2204:21)\n    at callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.policrypto&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:2189:33)",
    "config": {
        "transitional": {
            "silentJSONParsing": true,
            "forcedJSONParsing": true,
            "clarifyTimeoutError": false
        },
        "adapter": [
            "xhr",
            "http"
        ],
        "transformRequest": [
            null
        ],
        "transformResponse": [
            null
        ],
        "timeout": 0,
        "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
        "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
        "maxContentLength": -1,
        "maxBodyLength": -1,
        "env": {},
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
        },
        "method": "get",
        "url": "https://api.getgeoapi.com/v2/currency/convert?api_key=a6d2b23eb2ae0f35e5b6aa0bff7541be101bccb6"
    },
    "code": "ERR_NETWORK",
    "status": null
}

Could someone translate it to me ?
